# Entity Relationship Diagram: Can someone verify my ERD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, erd, entity-relationship

I have made an ERD diagram (well kind of as it doesn't adhere to all the principles of an ERD diagram).

Following are the requirements:

1. Manager/user can have many projects
2. The user can enter many bugs
3. A bug has a creator(user)
4. A bug has a developer who'll solve the bug(user)
5. A bug belongs to a project
6. A project can have many users
7. A project can have many bugs too.
8. The bug has a descriptive title and deadline and a screenshot, type, and status
9. Screen shot should be an image either .png or .gif no other type of image is allowed.
10. Description and the screenshot is not compulsory but title and status and type are compulsory.
11. The title of a bug should be unique throughout the project
12. Type can have two values (feature, bug)
13. Status is a drop down having values (new, started, completed) if it's a feature or (new, started and resolved) if it's a bug.

[image: ERD Diagram]

Here is my understanding.

1. There is a User table that will contain the (unique) ID (I may use UUID for that), Username, Email, UserType (Enum: Manager, Developer, QA), and encrypted User password.
2. A User can have multiple projects so that's why it has 1:Many relationships with the table Project. This table will have a unique Project ID, Manager ID (The creator of the project), and a project title.
3. I'm thinking of creating a 3rd table i.e. Working On, which will keep track of which user is currently present under the project (Requirement 5). Project ID and User Id, both will be FKs from respective tables and their combination will make a Primary Key. Is this approach feasible?
4. Each project can have multiple Bugs, so 1:Many relationships will be defined between Project and Bug. Bug ID will be the primary key.
5. Each bug can have an optional set of screenshot(s) (Max 10), which I'm thinking of storing in another table Screenshots. Its primary key will be composed of BugId and ImageID.

Can anyone please go through this logic and help me in identifying any errors in this approach? It is very important that I correctly categorize my databases so that implementation in Ruby on Rails becomes easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a generic database design question and not really much to do with Rails. If you were to express the above as some very stripped-back model classes, we'd know that you understood the likes of [`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association), [`has_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) and so-forth, and could at least verify it for Rails on that level. That said, at a glance it looks generally OK; some things you might want to consider:

- You don't have to get this right first time, although of course it's always nice to get it as close as you can. It's easy to write migrations in Rails to change data layers, and no matter how good your initial design, applications and requirements evolve - your data will too.
- You ought to call the primary key in all tables `id`. Only the foreign keys for relationships should be of the form `foo_id`. Your ERD also doesn't name the fields as they'd be in the database; you've "humanised" them with capitalisation and spaces. It'd be a little clearer if you used Rails naming conventions for that so we could, again, see that this was understood. I wonder if you might come from a Microsoft/C#-style background given the capitalisation and tendency to give the primary keys longer names.
- "Working On" is just a join table and perhaps does not need to be extracted specifically, though I know there's been a more recent movement in the Rails community to dislike ["has and belongs to many"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) in favour of ["has many through"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). Personally I don't mind it most of the time; "Working On"  just joins "user" to "project" and using a standard Rails naming convention HABTM relationship will let you do `user.projects` and `project.users` easily enough, without worrying about maintaining the "thing in the middle".
- I personally quite like using enumerations in PostgreSQL for columns with fixed arrays of values, *but* they are a little fiddly in Rails and an area where migrations are more difficult. You will probably find it easier to just use an indexed text field (depending on your database - you don't say what the engine will be) and have the corresponding Rails model define a series of constants for [validating values](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). This makes it easier to extend in future.

```rb
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  STATUS_OPEN    = 'open'
  STATUS_FIXED   = 'fixed'
  STATUS_WONTFIX = 'wont_fix'
  
  STATUSES = Set[
    STATUS_OPEN,
    STATUS_FIXED,
    STATUS_WONTFIX
  ]

  validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: STATUSES }
  # ...
end
```